# Regression Line for points

Tags: probability, statistics

A nonparametric regression model (incomplete) is shown in Figure 1  with the 3-nearest neighbours average method and the formula for this is $\frac{\sum y_j}{3}$.

Three nearest neighbour’s average method computes regression line $h(x)$, from the average of three nearest neighbours of the output, for finding a regression point. In the below figure for $X=4$ the three nearest neighbours of the output are $y_1=5,\:y_2=5.2,\:y_3=6$

The question is: What is the value of $h(x)$ for the point $X=4$

[image: Figure 1]

So am I stupid if the formula states that $\frac{\sum y_j}{3}$ it gives me $ (5 + 5.2 + 6) / 3$ which is the answer then or am I confused?

Comment: It sounds like you understood it perfectly well.